# Pseudocode to compute some regresion procedures

Tags: self-study, lasso, ridge-regression, stepwise-regression

I need some documentation to code the following regressions procedures:

- Forward - backward stepwise selection
- Ridge regression
- The Lasso
- Principal components regression
- Partial least squares

I am doing some abstract about linear methods for regression and I want to code by myself this methods in R to be able to understand them.

I already read the chapter 3 of this book [The elements of statistical learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) where they are explained but I need some adicional explanation on this methods to be able to code them

I suppose that R has this algorithm already implemented but I want to code them by myself for better understanding.